# Adicionar imagens dinamicamente com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Como adicionar uma imagem dinamicamente dentro desta `div` com JavaScript ?

```
div class="toad" id="mushs">
    <img id="image" src="mush.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para criar elementos dinamicamente em JavaScript, basta utilizar a função [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) passando o nome da tag que deseja criar como argumento (no caso é a tag `<img>`).

Depois de ter criado o elemento de imagem, defina no atributo `src` o caminho da imagem e adicione o elemento que você criou dentro da `div` com o [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function criaImagem(){
    const div = document.getElementById("imagens");
    
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = prompt("Digite o nome ou link da imagem: ");
    
    div.appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<div id="imagens"></div>
<button onclick="criaImagem();">Criar Imagem</button>
```

Comment: Não é bom esquecer de usar um `let` ou `const` ao declarar variáveis... :)

Comment: Costume de Python kkkk

Comment: Criei um botao para adicionar uma imagem usando teu codigo como apoio mas nao esta funcionando(a imagem esta na mesma pasta do arquivo js) function addImg() {
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = 'mush.png';
    document.getElementById('mushs').appendChild('image');
}

Comment: @DouglasKramer o problema é que você está passando uma string no método `appendChild` e não sua imagem.

Answer (score 4):

Além do `createElement`, demonstrado em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436912/69296), há o [construtor `Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image), exclusivo para criar elementos `img` — [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', appendImage);

function appendImage() {
  const div = document.querySelector('#images');
    
  const image = new Image(200, 200); // Largura (width) e altura (height).
  image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPUgS.png';
    
  div.appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<button>Criar Imagem</button>
<div id="images"></div>
```

O construtor `Image` é similar à API `document.createElement('img')`, porém aceita como argumentos a largura e altura da imagem.